# pip install pyodbc fails

Tags: python, pip, pyodbc

I am trying to install pyodbc in my docker container launched using lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 image.

Command : `pip install pyodbc`

I receive below error.

```
bash-4.2# pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.30.tar.gz (266 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /var/lang/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/p
ip-install-vp296l1s/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vp296l1s/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'
;f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"
');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-_0gnru3p
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vp296l1s/pyodbc/
  Complete output (14 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pyodbc' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=
4.0.30 -I/var/lang/include/python3.8 -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/buffer.o -Wn
o-write-strings
  In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
  src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
   #include <sql.h>
            ^~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you try upgrading your pip?

Comment: I can successfully install `pyodbc==4.0.27`

Comment: Looks like you're missing dependencies. Try install the dev packages for your database.

Comment: [This wiki page](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install#installing-on-linux) shows several examples of installing pyodbc on Linux. See if one of them helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyodbc%5D+linux